# error when running python asyncio socks proxy server in a thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I am using python3 asyncio_socks_server library to run a socks proxy, my program is supposed to run a socks proxy in a thread and an HTTP server on another thread then continue execution.
Here is my socks_proxy.py:

```
import socket
from asyncio_socks_server.__version__ import __version__
from asyncio_socks_server.app import SocksServer

class SocksProxy:
    def __init__(self, local_ip, port):
        args = []
        config_args = {
                "LISTEN_HOST": local_ip,
                "LISTEN_PORT": port,
                "AUTH_METHOD": 0,
                "ACCESS_LOG": 0,
                "DEBUG": 1,
                "STRICT": 0,
            }

        app = SocksServer(
                config=None,
                env_prefix="AIOSS_",
                **{k: v for k, v in config_args.items() if v is not None},
            )
        app.run()

def startSocksProxy(local_ip, port):
    s = SocksProxy(local_ip, port)
```

main.py:

```
import threading
from modules.util.socks_proxy import startSocksProxy
from modules.logger.logger import Logger 

if "__main__" == __name__:
    logger = Logger()
    remoteLog = threading.Thread(target=startLoggerServer)
    remoteLog.start()
    socksProxy = threading.Thread(target=startSocksProxy, args=(LOCAL_IP, 7000))
    socksProxy.start()
```

The HTTP server starts fine, however, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "j:\WormScanner\modules\util\socks_proxy.py", line 35, in startSocksProxy
    s = SocksProxy(local_ip, port)
  File "j:\WormScanner\modules\util\socks_proxy.py", line 26, in __init__
    app = SocksServer(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\asyncio_socks_server\app.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
```

and the socks proxy doesn't start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who ever faces this problem, it worked fine when I used multiprocessing:

```
if "__main__" == __name__:
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    remoteLog = multiprocessing.Process(target=startLoggerServer)
    remoteLog.start()
    socksProxy = multiprocessing.Process(target=startSocksProxy, args=(LOCAL_IP, 7000))
    socksProxy.start()
```